# Flyway: Migrating multiple databases

Tags: flyway

Is it possible to migrate multiple databases with the same data? I know the schema parameter but as far as I understood, it's for tables located in different databases / schemas. Not to duplicate the migrations to a different database.

How would the config look like for maven?

The reason is, that I have one schema for unit testing only and want to have the data as in another environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just run Flyway once for each DB. Maven profiles or plugin executions are what you need here.